# Circles preview in QGIS for TripAdvisor API

Tags: qgis

I'm going to use the API provided by TripAdvisor (see here: https://developer-tripadvisor.com/content-api/documentation/) to download hotels in some municipalitys from their servers. Data is requested by specifying coordinates of a point (centre of a circle) and the radius of the circles itself. I wanted to know if QGIS allows to draw a preview of these circles over the region object of studying and, if yes, in which way.

Comment: Do you want the user to draw a circle on a Qgis map canvas so you can then call the API with the circle x,y,radius? Suggest you need to create a circular rubber band using the QgsRubberBand class. http://qgis.org/api/classQgsRubberBand.html

Comment: @Spacedman Thanks you're right, but how about using the function in vector -> research tools -> regular points? (https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_ftools.html). I don't know if it's what I'm searching for, maybe you have some experience with that.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Is the *user* drawing a circle interactively or is Qgis drawing a circle based on some circle specification?

Comment: @Spacedman I wanted to fill the area with circles of known radius and centre coordinates just to have a starting point for requesting data through TripAdvisor API

Comment: When you say "fill the area" do you mean you want to create a set of circles that overlap and completely cover the Qgis map canvas area? And create them as a new layer in Qgis?

Comment: @Spacedman Yes, sorry for my English, but that is exactly what I'm trying to do

Comment: Is one big circle not enough? Is there a maximum radius? Perhaps you should edit your question a bit for clarification...

Comment: @Spacedman It would be better to create multiple circles if possible